# Convergence of Sequences in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let {$\alpha_n$} be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \alpha_n = \alpha$$

Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \alpha_n ^3 = \alpha ^3$$

---

My first notion is to use an $\epsilon$, $n_0$ argument, and try to prove that given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n_0 \in N$ such that $|\alpha_n ^3 - \alpha ^3| < \epsilon$ for every $n \geq n_0$.

However, I'm not sure where to continue from if I go down that path. Does anyone have a suggestion for a jumping off point for the rest of the proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please replace $\to$ by $=$, twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon$, choose $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$ we have $|a_n-a|<\min\bigg(1 \frac{\varepsilon}{|a|^2+|a|(1+|a|)+(1+|a|)^2}\bigg)$ so $|a_n| \le1+|a|$
 \begin{align}|a_n^3-a^3|=|a-a_n||a^2+aa_n+a_n^2|\le |a_n-a|(|a|^2+|a||a_n|+|a_n|^2)\\
\le|a_n-a|\big[|a|^2+|a|(1+|a|)+(1+|a|)^2\big]\\<\varepsilon \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since $\alpha_n \to \alpha$ there is an $n_0$ such that $|\alpha_n - \alpha| < \sqrt[3]{\epsilon}$ for every $n \geq n_0$. Now raise both sides to the $3$rd power, which is allowed as the function $x \mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: As another approach, since $x^3$ is a continuous function, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} (\alpha_n^3)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha_n\right)^3.
$$